# CardView background color doesn't change even after using app:cardBackgroundColor property

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-cardview

I am making effort to change my cardView background color to a different color other than the default color set in style with the `colorSurface` property.
I am aware `colorSuface` is responsible for a `cardView` color, but it is surprisingly difficult to change it color in `XML`.
I have tried the following singly and together but there is no effect.

```
android:background="@color/purple_200"
app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/purple_200"
android:backgroundTint="@color/purple_200"
```

I will appreciate help.

Here is my `styles` code
`<item name="colorSurface">@color/app10</item>`

The reason I don't want to change the `colorSurface` property is because, that is the default desired color I want for all `cardView` but in this particular layout, I want to style my row of `cardView` widgets with tones of a color, unfortunately, it is not responding.

Comment: `MaterialCardView` uses `colorSurface` as its default `app:cardBackgroundColor` value. Plain `CardView` does not. In any case, setting the `app:cardBackgroundColor` attribute directly on the `<CardView>` element should definitely work, so we're gonna need more information. Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Yeah, @MikeM. you are right on point. Setting `app:cardBackgroundColor` should definitely change it's color. I figured out the issue was an `imageView` inside the `cardView` that conspired against my happiness. I will post the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue was the color set to an `imageView` inside the `cardView` was overlaying the color of the `cardView`.
Another possible cause of this kind of behaviour is if the `cardView` was inside a layout whose elevation (layout) is possibly greater than the `cardView`.

Thanks @Mike M for asserting that `cardView` doesn't disappoint in this case.